# Looking for a function with certain limits and derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

I'm looking for a differntiable function f (I want to use it as a loss function for a machine learning task) where:

\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to1^{-}} f(x) &= -\inf  &&&  f^{\prime}(0^{+}) &= \inf\\
\lim_{x\to0^{+}} f(x) &= 0 &&& f^{\prime}(1^{-}) &= -\inf
\end{aligned}

How can I find such function?

[image]

Comment: According to your sketch, the derivative at zero is negative, that's why I added a negative sign. Now that you removed the negative sign, the graph doesn't match the equations.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin When you approach zero from the right side, isn't the derivative positive?

Comment: The definition of the derivative doesn't "flip" but merely "shifted" when you approach from different sides. Approaching from the right as $x \to 0^{+}$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\delta x) - f(x)}{(x+\delta x)-x} = \lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{f(\delta x) - f(0)}{\delta x}$. From the left $x \to 0^{-}$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x-\delta x)}{x - (x-\delta x)} = \lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{f(0) - f(-\delta x)}{\delta x}$.

Comment: These two limits can be different when the function $f$ is not "smooth". For example, when $f$ looks like a top tip of a triangle (upward cusp), the left derivative will be positive and the right derivative will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

On first random guess, one function that works is 
$$
f(x)=-\frac{\sqrt x}{1-x}.
$$
One can delay the "falling to $-\infty$" by taking powers of $x$:$$
g(x)=-\frac{k\sqrt x}{1-x^m}.
$$
The larger the $m$, the later the function goes pitching down; and the larger the $k$, the lower the change in convexity will be.